# Can't parse a static JSON file in Django 1.8

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, django-staticfiles

I have the following tree:

```
myDjangoSite/
    ...
    myApp/
        ...
        static/
            ...
            myApp/
                myData.json
```

And I have this view.py file:

```
import json
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.staticfiles.templatetags.staticfiles import static


url = static('myApp/myData.json')

json_data = open(url)

def helloWorld(request):

    return render(request, 'myApp/index.html')
```

...and when I access to the webpage, the browsers shows this message:

**IOError at /
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static/myApp/myData.json'**

I don't understand why it says "no such file or directory", if the file DOES exist and how to solve it.

Comment: Did you configure your static files as described in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/) ?

Comment: @alp, `static` is not intended for this. You know.

Comment: @danihp is there any django documentation which suggests NOT to use static reference from server side? Or it is meant to be used ONLY form the client side? I'd appreciate any reference because I don't recall reading any. Thank you.

Comment: `static`creates a URL path, starting from STATIC_URL. It does not create a file path, which would need to start at STATIC_ROOT.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I completed my answer (bellow) to cover `collectstatic` case, I guess is right. Thanks about to explain my comment to alp.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new project on 1.8 setting `BASE_DIR` var is created:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Use this var as base for your file path:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> import os
>>> f=os.path.join( settings.BASE_DIR, 'myApp/static/myApp/myData.json' )
>>> f
'/home/dani/tmp/ppdpd/p/myApp/myData.json'
>>> json_data = open(f)
```

**Notice** than `static` is intended to get path to out of the box clients, from navigator side, remotely, from Internet. And not from your server side django app.

**Notice** may be you invoke `collectstatic` when you deploy your app, then the right path will be `settings.STATIC_ROOT` something like:

```
>>> f=os.path.join( settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'myApp/myData.json' )
```